# How to get the rank of a row in mysql query

Tags: mysql

this my database structure

table : players

```
id  | name      |  score
1   | Bob       |  600
2   | Alex      |  1400
3   | John      |  800
4   | sara      |  2000
```

I need to select john's row and count what is the john' rank OrderBy score

as you see john is 3rd (800) , sara is 1st (2000), Alex is 2nd (1400) in score ranks

```
Select @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank form players where id=3 OrderBy score
```

any idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ROW\_NUMBER() in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by a subquery and count the players who has score more than the score of a certian id

```
Select count(*) as rank 
from players 
where score > (select score from players where id=3)
```

But if you want to have other information beside the rank you can do it by

```
SELECT ranks . *
FROM (    
   SELECT @rownum := @rownum +1 ‘rank’, p.id, p.score
   FROM players p, (SELECT @rownum :=0)r
   ORDER BY score DESC
) ranks
WHERE id =3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select rank
from
(
  Select id, name, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank 
  from players 
  cross join (select @rownum := 0) r
  Order By score desc
) tmp
where id = 3
```

Comment: "From" clause is mistyped, but this solution works perfect without having to run 2 queries (one for setting up a variable and another to run rank the records).

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to do a self join, where the joined table score is greater (to get the rows with a higher score) and just do a count:-

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM players a
INNER JOIN players b
ON a.score >= b.score
WHERE a.id = 3
```

Question is what to do with equal scores.